# symfony3 how to set input data with query result

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

What I need is simple, I can make it with php, but I want to user FormBuilder.
I have this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('number',NumberType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Number',
            'attr' => array(
                'readonly' => "readonly"
                )
            )
        )
        ->add('year',NumberType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Year',
            'data' => date('Y'),
            'attr' => array(
                'readonly' => "readonly"
                )
            )
        )
```

And What I need is to search for the last `number` of this `year` and add the next one. If there is no number for this year, it will show 1. Is this posible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thinking you're wanting a [DataTransformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)  Otherwise please show the logic for the desired result. It's difficult to understand `search` and `add the next one` terms. I'm guessing you mean `2017` the searched number would be `7` and add the next one (`2018`) would be `8` so `8+7`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking time to comment. As you can see `year` is always the actual year. so if in the table you have 2017-1,2017-2,2017-3 ({year}-{number}), I need to show 2017-4 inside those input. That make sense for you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your query result, you can use the `FormType::buildForm` `$options` argument to pass in your custom data to the form.

You will need to define the custom options in the `configurOptions` method for them to be accepted. By using `setDefaults` the values defined will be set if the option is not supplied in the options array.

```
class FormType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder
             //...
            ->add('number',NumberType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Number',
                'data' => $options['number'],
                'attr' => array(
                    'readonly' => "readonly"
                    )
                )
            )
            ->add('year',NumberType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Year',
                'data' => $options['year'],
                'attr' => array(
                    'readonly' => "readonly"
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'year' => date('Y'),
            'number' => 1
        ]);
    }

   //...

}
```

Then in your controller run your query and pass the custom data to the form builder options.

```
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    $options = ['year' => date('Y')];
    /** 
     * query data
     * @returns integer|null default: 1
     */
    $options['number'] = $em->getRepository('app:Entity')->filterYearNumber($options['year']) ?: 1;
    $form = $this->createForm(FormType::class, $data, $options);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
         //... handle submission
    }

    return $this->render('form.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Comment: that's actually a nice answer, thanks a lot. But is that possible to add the query inside the FormType class? Another problem I see is that I can't send option number or option year. I can send just the options on this list: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html

Comment: Sure, you could always create your form as a service and inject the entity manager or entity repository into your class and call it directly.

Comment: Yes you could, but it is not advisable to need to maintain the FormType class to always require the EntityManager. When you declare the `configureOptions` you can expand the Form to accept any value. For example using the same FormType object to maintain create, edit, and delete or special use-case forms for the desired model as well. So you don't need separate classes for each operation. This way the Form has only what it needs to be a form and is easier to expand upon elsewhere.

Comment: An example of passing the entity manager to the Form https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html